Huge spaces between symbols in cells like "Input" and "DisplayFormula" in Mathematica 14
With the same font "Source Code Pro", the spacing in cells of type "Input" and "Output" have different sizes.

How can I reduce the space between characters to an acceptable size like in "Output"?

14.1 wll fix this bug.
